# Custom Unwind Segue in UINavigationController

Tags: xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I have searched so many posts but could not get an answer to this question. I have a UITabBarController from which I present a UINavigationController using a custom segue. It presents well but the issue is there is no way to unwind the same way when I press say the back button. I have created a custom unwind segue class as well, but there is no way at all to programmatically or through storyboards create an unwind action and assign a custom unwind segue class in the UINavigationController. Any help ?